# Using Nlog logger with ECS layout, in kibana the json object appear as a string instead of multiple properties

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, nlog, elastic-common-schema

I'm working on some .Net framework application and i've been asked to send the logs to elasticsearch using kibana as the UI.
To have something that is standardized i have to implement ECS (Elastic Common Schema).

Looking at the example we have on ECS [github](https://github.com/elastic/ecs-dotnet/tree/master/src/Elastic.CommonSchema.NLog) we only have to implement it on the following way:

[image]

Instead of sending to console, like we have on the example i send it to elastic search

[image]

The output from it, would be a nice Json object...

Maybe it is expected that on kibana we would see something like the following (`Kibana` - `Discover`):

[image]

Looking at that, probably the Json Object is supposed to be treated as a string and everything goes inside the `message` property, but that is not what i'm looking for, i want that json to be divided in many properties.

Since i'm new to Elastic stack world, i've tried to create a template inside the `Index Management` page and the performing there manual mappings like `message._metadata.url` to not treat some properties as part of the string but without success.

I'm having trouble finding useful information to solve this problem, can anyone give an hint?

UPDATE:

I found the property `enableJsonLayout="true"`that we can put on the target of `Nlog` that indeed turns whats on the Json layout as properties on ElasticSearch which is good.

[image]

Is this the right way to use ECS?
How can i add aditional properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enable this `enableJsonLayout="true"` then it means that the configured Layout has to handle everything. For EcsLayout then you can find the documentation here:

https://github.com/elastic/ecs-dotnet/tree/master/src/Elastic.CommonSchema.NLog

EcsLayout will by default include all LogEvent Properties as metadata. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging

But you can explicit add extra metadata-items:

```
<layout xsi:type="EcsLayout">
   <metadata name="MyProperty" layout="MyPropertyValue" />
</layout>
```

Comment: Cool, you're a lifesaver that metadata property data works! Where did you found that we can add that extra metadata items? I looked at some of the EcsLayout and Nlog code and documentation and did not found that.

Comment: @Nmaster88 Created pull-request to update documentation. Right now you can get a preview here: https://github.com/snakefoot/ecs-dotnet/tree/master/src/Elastic.CommonSchema.NLog

Comment: Thanks for the PR, i see now that probably this attribute ```[ArrayParameter(typeof(TargetPropertyWithContext), "metadata")]``` is what allows this props to be added on the xml. Btw is it possible to know what are the objective of each one? metadata i already see that is suposed to add new props inside the ```metadata``` object, but the others ```labels``` and ```tags``` i can only guess.

Comment: I noted that these ```metadata``` props, that i add through the ```web.config``` always appear even when they have no value in elasticsearch, which means that on kibana i see empty fields, is it possible to change this behaviour? not send the prop when it is not needed.

Comment: @Nmaster88 "Labels" and "Tags" are part of the ECS-schema: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs/current/ecs-base.html